# WordPress permalink change throws 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, permalinks, internal-server-error

I am changing my **permalink structure** in wordpress admin panel,

after changing this, when I click on post its throwing **Internal server error**

if changing it to default permalink structure , its working fine.

changing permalink setting in my localhost is working fine , but in staging server its throwing internal errors, I checked my .htaccess file in staging server , new rules are getting updated , but its showing internal error issue which is not coming in localserver.

I am using Wpengine webhost .

and I am in staging server mode.

How can I get rid of this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk to your webhost; your changes are not being written to .htaccess or your webhost doesn't allow .htaccess and mod_rewrite to be used.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

If you're on a Windows server, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

Comment: I checked my htaccess file, new rules are getting updated , but showing error.

Comment: Talk to your webhost; they may not allow mod_rewrite to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to rewrite the url two times:

1. .htaccess file
2. WP Permalink settings

Get rid of your .htaccess file
(or comment first line)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase ./
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . ./index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed wordpress in a subdirectory you need to change the line 
`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` (last line before /IfModule) with  `RewriteRule . subdirectoryName/index.php [L]`
Change subdirectoryName with the name of the subdirectory that wordpress is installed.